# I wonder why NDSolve is not responding

Tags: differential-equations

```
solution = NDSolve[{Derivative[1][x][t] == 0.00333` - 100000 c - 0.0005776226504666211` x 
- 370000.` P x, Derivative[1][c][t] == -100000.18890333334` c + 370000.` P x, 
Derivative[1][p][t] == 0.1327433628318584` + 100000.18833` c - 0.0005776` P - 
         370000.` P x, x[0] == 0, c[0] == 0, p[0] == 0}, x, {t, 0, 100}]
```

When  I type this in, it returns an `NDSolve` object back to me.
I wonder what is the reason for that. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

The answer to your question is in the error message,

> NDSolve::dvnoarg: The function c appears with no arguments.

You need to have the unknown functions in the form `c[t]`, `x[t]`, `P[t]`.

In some places, you have used capital `P` and at other, small `p`.

```
eq1 = x'[t] == 0.00333 - 100000*c[t] - 0.0005776226504666211*x[t] - 370000*P[t]*x[t]

eq2 = c'[t] == -100000.18890333334*c[t] + 370000*P[t]*x[t]

eq3 = P'[t] == 0.1327433628318584 + 100000.18833*c[t] - 0.0005776*P[t] - 370000*P[t]*x[t]

sol = NDSolve[{eq1, eq2, eq3, x[0] == 0, c[0] == 0, P[0] == 0}, {x, P, c}, {t, 0, 100}]
```